# Web Component - Lighting Out - Load a page

Tags: lightning-web-components, url, lightning-out

I have a new lightning challenge to solve.

For a project we built a lightning web component, and we exposed it to an external portal through lightning out.

One of the requirement is to be able to load a new page, on the same browser tab that contains the lightning out component.

We started from the following code and we adapt it to work as a web component
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005WRKQA2

But the result that we obtained was to open a new page. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use window.top.location to load the new page. You can't use force:navigateToURL within Lightning Out in the same tab/window.